# Rock,Paper,Scissors progress of the game in app

Tags: android, android-studio, crash

so I want to create a Rock Paper Scissors app that should work like this:
In the first screen you enter the names of the 2 players.
In the second screen there are the names of the players and the score of each player near it.The progress is that you need to click a button,and after you click it,in each player's side,random image(rock paper or scissors) will appear and the winner will get a point,or nobody will if its a draw.
**NOTE:This might not be an error in the code based on what i've seen when I tried to search for the message i'm getting while debugging so you may want to  look at it first.**
I would appreciate some comments on the code though.

I checked if the names that i'm passing from the first activity to the second one before I had started to work on the button and the app worked fine.
But after I wrote the code for the OnClickListener, the app just crashes instantly after the first activity when I run it. It is my first time working with images like that so i'm not sure that if used it properly. I have created some functions so the code will be more readable without knowing exactly what i'm doing though because i'm pretty new to android.

first activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button startBtn;
        startBtn = findViewById(R.id.startBtn);
            startBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    EditText p2Name=findViewById(R.id.p2EditText);
                    EditText p1Name=findViewById(R.id.p1EditText);
                    String name1=p2Name.getText().toString();
                    String name2=p1Name.getText().toString();
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Game.class);
                    intent1.putExtra("name1",name1);
                    intent1.putExtra("name2",name2);
                    MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent1);
                }

        });


    }
```

second activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);


        String p1Name;
        String p2Name;
        if (getIntent().hasExtra("name1")) {
            p1Name = getIntent().getStringExtra("name1");
            TextView p1NView = findViewById(R.id.p1);
            p1NView.setText(p1Name);
        }
        if (getIntent().hasExtra("name2")) {
            p2Name = getIntent().getStringExtra("name2");
            TextView p2NView = findViewById(R.id.p2);
            p2NView.setText(p2Name);
        }

        Button NRound=findViewById(R.id.newRoundBtn);
        NRound.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    TextView score1=findViewById(R.id.score1View);
                    TextView score2=findViewById(R.id.score2View);
                    int p1Score = Integer.parseInt(score1.getText().toString());
                    int p2Score = Integer.parseInt(score2.getText().toString());
                    String[] RPS = new String[]{"rock", "paper", "scissors"};
                    Random r = new Random();
                    String p1Hand;
                    String p2Hand;
                    p1Hand = RPS[r.nextInt(3)];
                    p2Hand = RPS[r.nextInt(3)];
                    showImages(p1Hand,p2Hand);
                    String result=findWinner(p1Hand,p2Hand);
                    switch (result){
                        case "player1":
                            p1Score++;
                            score1.setText(String.valueOf(p1Score));
                        case "player2":
                            p2Score++;
                            score2.setText(String.valueOf(p2Score));
                     if(score1.getText().equals('3') || score2.getText().equals('3')){
                         Intent end=new Intent(Game.this,EndScreen.class);
                         Game.this.startActivity(end);
                     }
                    }
                }
            });
        update();
    }

public static  String findWinner(String hand1,String hand2){
        if(hand1.equals(hand2)){
            return "draw";
        }
        String both=hand1.concat(hand2);
        if(both.equals("rockscissor") || both.equals("paperrock")||both.equals("scissorspaper")){
            return "player1";
        }else{
            return "player2";
        }

    }

public void showImages(String hand1,String hand2){
        ImageView rock1=findViewById(R.id.rock1);
        ImageView paper1=findViewById(R.id.paper1);
        ImageView scissors1=findViewById(R.id.scissors1);
        ImageView rock2=findViewById(R.id.rock2);
        ImageView paper2=findViewById(R.id.paper2);
        ImageView scissors2=findViewById(R.id.scissors2);
        switch (hand1){
            case "rock":
                rock1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            case "paper":
                paper1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            case "scissors":
                scissors1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        switch (hand2){
            case "rock":
                rock2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            case "paper":
                paper2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            case "scissors":
                scissors2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

public void update(){
        ImageView[] images=new ImageView[6];
         for (ImageView image:images)
         {
             if(image.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE){
                 image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             }

         }
     }
```

Logs
Edit:now after I have posted and seen the logs I understood what was the problem. I forgot to initialize the imageView array in a function and I was just looping over null array,trying to get its visibility.And Now it does not crash.
I didn't know about this so thanks anyways for telling me to post it.(thought errors should show up in the console or something).
Now I am dealing with another problem,I will try to solve it on my own though.

```
Process: com.example.rockpaperscissors, PID: 11607
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.rockpaperscissors/com.example.rockpaperscissors.Game}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.widget.ImageView.getVisibility()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3260)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3396)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2009)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7319)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:934)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.widget.ImageView.getVisibility()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.rockpaperscissors.Game.update(Game.java:71)
        at com.example.rockpaperscissors.Game.onCreate(Game.java:65)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7783)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7772)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3235)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3396) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2009) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7319) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:934)
```

I tried to debug the app and at the last line of the first activity,the message that shows up is: source code does not match the byte code.

Comment: so if I understood correctly you're facing a crash, right? You migh want as well post the error log so we can help you better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try to clean the project and rebuild it. 
In order for us to help you with the crash, we need to see the logs. Please add that as well.

About your code:

- MainActivity.class

  - Try validating user input before passing it to the next activity.
- Game.class (assuming this is also an activity so try renaming it to GameActivity.class)

  - When you are retrieving data from the intent, it's best practice to create a constant and make it public that you can use in the main activity as well (if you make a typo, it's hard to find the problem)
    Something like: public static final String NAME_ONE_KEY = "name1";
  - I don't see the need of using a string array, identify those actions by integer and comment it so you and others who read your code can understand it.
  - It seems like you have a lot of child elements in your game layout file
        Add the images into the drawable folder, create one image view for each player and update the image source.

Finally, save the state so you don't loose the data on device rotation.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.I have found the problem now after I looked on the logs(Didn't know errors show up there before) and it works now. I have a question though how do I save the state?

Comment: @TheNiv override the onsaveInstanceState and save whatever you need. Retrieve these values in the onCreate. Here is more information https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

Comment: @TheNiv You have lots of options on how to save state. I'm assuming you want it after app closes and is reopened after an extended time IE hours or days?.  The easiest option would be to look up SharedPreferences.  That should be good enough for a basic use case and a basic application.  You can also look at local databases to store information and retrieve it.  I'm a big fan of https://realm.io/blog/realm-for-android/.  But i'd start small and do some research on shared preferences.